# Maximum Number of Fields in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, fields

I couldn't find any restriction on the maximum number of fields/columns while creating a DataExtension using the SOAP API. There seems to be some restriction on the name but none on the max number of columns/fields. Is there any such restriction?

Here's the [documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) I have reviewed so far.

Comment: There are is no documented limitation, but how many fields were you intending to create exactly? 1 or 1 million? It's not best practice to create hundreds of fields, but if you think you need to, there are other options for storing structured data in fields (e.g. in a JSON object). Perhaps you can share your use case?

Comment: I am writing a wrapper for the inserting records into an existing dataExtension using soap api. wanted to know this for validation purposes. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From inspecting [the wsdl](https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl) (the API schema), the `maxOccurs` for Data Extension fields is `unbounded` which implies that there is no limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any limit on the number of fields as it is a datatable, I have been working with data extension that has 250 fields  via API.