# Are there any Salesforce Marketing Cloud logs available which show the start/end times for synchronised data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization

I currently have synchronised data extensions set up to pull data from Salesforce into Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I'm trying to ascertain whether I can move the sync frequency of one of those extensions from 1 hour, down to 15 mins - without creating a performance impact/breaking anything.

As part of my investigation I'm trying to find the existing sync start/end times to give me a sense of how quickly the sync in question currently completes - but I can't find anything. The sync in question is for the Opportunity object - which holds 4m+ rows/133 fields - and is growing.

Can anyone help me to better understand where the limits are?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific answer to your question about how impactful it would be to increase the syncing frequency from every hour to every 15 minutes.

There are some [official best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5) that suggest you limit the number of synced fields to 250. As for the volume of the records, there is [this good answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309151/what-are-known-limitations-on-number-of-attributes-in-data-extension) and [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/optimizing_api_calls_and_data_structures_to_improve_performance_in_the_salesforce_marketing_cloud.html) that might give you an idea. Based on that you can consider your changes now and later in the future but besides that, unfortunately, there is no way how you can track synchronization times and measure MCC performance.